# Java Azure Function Deployment fails - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: azure-functions

I have Java Functions, which have perfectly deployed to Azure from laptop A.
Now trying to deploy to function app from laptop B and getting error. Local debug is fine. Deployment to Azure fails.  What could be problem?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) 
on project MyFunctionsApp: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete 
C:\Azure\MyFunctionsApp\target\azure-functions\myfunctions- 
20200415001812419\MyFunctionsApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Can you show more details? Just like the pom.xml and your steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting PC seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly possible reason is your permission on the folder, make sure you have sufficient permissions to delete files in this folder.

Another is there's a process that's holding a lock on a file in some subfolder that Maven is trying to clean. So try to close the java process from the task manager and restart your eclipse.